# Customize DragUI of ListViewItem (UWP)

Tags: c#, listview, uwp, drag-and-drop, drag

ListView offers a [DragItemsStarting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.DragItemsStartingEventArgs) event that comes with according event args. However, unlike [DragStartingEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.DragStartingEventArgs) - common to other elements - it does not offer a DragUI, as far as I can tell. My only option is to use *DragOver* event which is very annoying.

So, I instead said I'll make the ListViewItem's content draggable. However, that backfired because now the *Click* event doesn't get through anymore, or only very rarely. Simply put, I either can customize the DragUI and not click my ListItems, or the DragUI looks bad, but I retain my functionality.

Is it possible to get a custom DragUI and have the click be handled by the ListView?

Answer (score 0):

You can still utilize `DragStarting`, but you have to add it to the item content itself within your `DataTemplate`:

```
<ListView>
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <Grid CanDrag="True" DragStarting="ItemDragStartingHandler">
                ...
           </Grid>
       </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

If that causes the click event not working properly, you could try customizing the `ListViewItem` container itself, which might work. Right-click the `ListView` in the designer or the Document Outline window, select **Edit Additional Templates**, and then **Edit Generated Item Container**. From the last menu select **Edit a Copy...**

[image: Edit additional templates]

You will get a `Style` which might be quite long, but within it you will find the the following:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <ListViewItemPresenter DragStarting="ItemDragStartingHandler" x:Name="Root" ...>
```

You can apply `DragStarting` event to the `ListViewItemPresenter` and that might satisfy your needs.

Comment: Is that different to making the content draggable in the code (except for where the event handler is located)? I will try it but I'm afraid that it'll again interfere with the click event.

Comment: It would seem that this still eats the click event somehow :/

Comment: Oh, I completely missed that part of the post... I have updated it with another idea

Comment: Unfortunately, adding a `DragStarting` handler to the `ListViewItemPresenter` does not seem to work. It is not called when item drags start.